# How to change the paragraphs color using JS and an onclick button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors, onclick

I'm using a button to display a mode where my paragraphs (and my headings but I'm not there yet) change color. I can change the background of my page by clicking this button but I can't change the paragraphs' color. Note that they have a class assigned.
Here is the following code on my JS page:

```
function chBackcolor(color) {
   document.body.style.background = color;
};
function changeColor(color) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('forma').onclick = changeColor;
}
```

And here is what I used on HTML:

```
`<input type="button" value="Mode Psychédélique" 
     onclick="chBackcolor('magenta'), changeColor('blue')">
```

`

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the color of each paragraph you may use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.forma').forEach(function(ele) {
     ele.style.color = color;
});
```

```js
function chBackcolor(color) {
    document.body.style.background = color;
};
function changeColor(color) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.forma').forEach(function(ele) {
        ele.style.color = color;
    });
}
```

```html
<p class="forma">paragraph1...............</p>
<p class="forma">paragraph2...............</p>
<p class="forma">paragraph3...............</p>
<input type="button" value="Mode Psychédélique" onclick="chBackcolor('magenta'), changeColor('blue')">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked ! One more question though; can I use this for several classes at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example loop the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) elements returned by [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) and then set the color using a for/of loop:

```
function changeColor(color) {
  for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('forma')) {
    e.style.color = color
  }
}
```

```js
function chBackcolor(color) {
  document.body.style.background = color;
}

function changeColor(color) {
  for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('forma')) {
    e.style.color = color
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Mode Psychédélique" onclick="chBackcolor('magenta'), changeColor('blue')">
<p class="forma">test1</p>
<p class="forma">test2</p>
<p class="forma">test3</p>
```

Another option could be using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax:

```
function changeColor(color) {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('forma')].forEach(e => e.style.color = color);
}
```

```js
function chBackcolor(color) {
  document.body.style.background = color;
}

function changeColor(color) {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('forma')].forEach(e => e.style.color = color);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Mode Psychédélique" onclick="chBackcolor('magenta'), changeColor('blue')">
<p class="forma">test1</p>
<p class="forma">test2</p>
<p class="forma">test3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `getElementsByClassName` document, the method returns an HTML Collection which could be accessed like an array. Try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('forma')[0].onclick = changeColor;
```

If you are confident that only one element has such class name. (In this case, I suggest you use the id selector instead of class name selector)

**Edit**: I rechecked your code and felt that `.onclick = changeColor` is quite weird

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection and not an array